# rearranging JSON with ramda.js - lens based on sibling element?

Tags: arrays, json, functional-programming, json-api, ramda.js

Here is my data structure (abbreviated, and *you can skip over this until you get to the heart of my question below*):

```
  var data = {
  jsonapi: { version: '1.0' },
  data: {
    type: 'mobile_screens',
    id: '1',
    attributes: { title: 'Watch' },
    relationships: {
      mobile_screen_components: {
        data: [
          { type: 'mobile_screen_components', id: '1_1' },
          { type: 'mobile_screen_components', id: '1_2' },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  included: [
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '5590720024001',
      attributes: {
        thumbnail: {
          width: 1280,
          url:
            'http://media2.XXXXX.com/BrightCove/694940094001/2017/09/27/694940094001_5590729403001_5590720024001-vs.jpg?pubId=694940094001',
          height: 720,
        },
        start_air_date: '2017-09-27T16:32:00.000Z',
        streams: [
          {
            url:
              'http://XXXXX-f.akamaihd.net/i/BrightCove/694940094001/2017/09/27/694940094001_55907,27023001_5590720024001,30873001_5590720024001,32416001_5590720024001,32423001_5590720024001,32792001_5590720024001,32896001_5590720024001,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8',
            mime_type: 'MP4',
          },
        ],
        last_modified_date: '2017-09-27T16:50:13.471Z',
        description: 'House Republicans renew call amid fresh Comey concerns',
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '5590670324001',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '5590665282001',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },
    },
    {
      id: '20fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76',
      type: 'articles',
      attributes: {
        fn__legacy_type: 'articles',
        title: 'Restaurant plans ginormous site near Wall Street, Ground Zero',
        fn__media_tags: ['business'],
        last_published_date: '2017-09-20T18:20:29.526Z',
        thumbnail: {
          image: {
            url:
              'https://secure.media.foxnews.com/BrightCove/990505083001/990505083001/2017/09/13/990505083001_5575086468001_5574853539001-vs.jpg?pubId=694940094001',
          },
        },
      },
      relationships: {
        components_relationships: {
          data: [
            {
              id: 'article_id_7',
              type: 'videos',
            },
            {
              id: 'article_id_8',
              type: 'videos',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7',
      type: 'articles',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },
      relationships: {
        ...
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'mobile_screen_components',
      id: '1_1',
      attributes: { display_type: 'shelf', title: 'Featured Playlist' },
      relationships: {
        videos: {
          data: [
            [
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590720024001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590670324001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590665282001' },
              {
                id: '20fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76',
                type: 'articles',
              },
              {
                id: 'e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7',
                type: 'articles',
              },
          ],
        },
        articles: {
          data: [
              {
                id: '20fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76',
                type: 'articles',
              },
              {
                id: 'e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7',
                type: 'articles',
              },
          ],
        }
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '1241186546001',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '1251429410001',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'mobile_screen_components',
      id: '1_2',
      attributes: { display_type: 'shelf', title: 'Live TV' },
      relationships: {
        videos: {
          data: [
            { type: 'videos', id: '1241186546001' },
            { type: 'videos', id: '1251429410001' },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      type: 'videos',
      id: '2013931500001',
      attributes: {
        ...
      },

    },
    {
      type: 'mobile_screen_components',
      id: '1_3',
      attributes: { display_type: 'shelf', title: 'Live Streams' },
      relationships: {
        videos: {
          data: [{ type: 'videos', id: '2013931500001' }],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

For each object in the `included` array, I would like to check of it has a `type` of "mobile_screen_components." If it does, I would like to grab all the objects inside that parent object's `relationship` property (e.g. 
`videos`, `articles`,  `shows`, etc.) and grab each respective `data` array. Finally, all these arrays would be concatenated, and place under a new `data` array, which will be a property of an `items` array, which is now the sole property of the original object.

That is to say that

```
{
      type: 'mobile_screen_components',
      id: '1_1',
      attributes: { display_type: 'shelf', title: 'Featured Playlist' },
      relationships: {
        videos: {
          data: [
            [
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590720024001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590670324001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590665282001' }
          ]
        },
        articles: {
          data: [
              {
                id: '20fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76',
                type: 'articles',
              },
              {
                id: 'e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7',
                type: 'articles',
              },
          ],
        }
      },
    }
```

would become

```
{
      type: 'mobile_screen_components',
      id: '1_1',
      attributes: { display_type: 'shelf', title: 'Featured Playlist' },
      relationships: {
        items: {
          data: [
            [
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590720024001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590670324001' },
              { type: 'videos', id: '5590665282001' },
              {
                id: '20fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76',
                type: 'articles',
              },
              {
                id: 'e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7',
                type: 'articles',
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
    }
```

I want to use a lens as to return to whole of the structure with just this transformation applied. My initial stab at this does not work:

```
const getMCRel = (type, rels) => {
  if (type === 'mobile_screen_components' ) {
    return rels
  }
  return undefined
} 
const findMCRel = R.compose(getMCRel, R.props(['type','relationships']));
const rLens = R.lens(findMCRel, R.assoc('relationships'));
const itemsWrapper = (arr) => ({"items": arr});
const result = R.map(R.over(rLens,R.compose(itemsWrapper, R.values)),data.included)
```

Comment: You might want to review [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There seems to be too much extraneous information in the sample.

Comment: its tricky to represent the complexity, but I cut a good bit out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't get you all of the way, but for the conversion of the "mobile_screen_components" part, you could use something like this:

```
const simplify = over(
  lensProp('relationships'), 
  pipe(pluck('data'), values, flatten, objOf('data'), objOf('items'))
)

simplify(stuff)
```

You can see this in action in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20stuff%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20%27mobile_screen_components%27%2C%0A%20%20id%3A%20%271_1%27%2C%0A%20%20attributes%3A%20%7B%20display_type%3A%20%27shelf%27%2C%20title%3A%20%27Featured%20Playlist%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20relationships%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20videos%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20%27videos%27%2C%20id%3A%20%275590720024001%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20%27videos%27%2C%20id%3A%20%275590670324001%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20type%3A%20%27videos%27%2C%20id%3A%20%275590665282001%27%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20articles%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%2720fb845a-72ad-4d5f-a27a-c01efd857f76%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27articles%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20%27e6e327ec-ebb2-4220-a391-41f798e654f7%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20%27articles%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20simplify%20%3D%20over%28%0A%20%20lensProp%28%27relationships%27%29%2C%20%0A%20%20pipe%28pluck%28%27data%27%29%2C%20values%2C%20flatten%2C%20objOf%28%27data%27%29%2C%20objOf%28%27items%27%29%29%0A%29%0Asimplify%28stuff%29)**.

And to test if your item is of the correct type, you simply use:

```
propEq('type', 'mobile_screen_component')
```

But your requirements are not clear enough to me to know if you want to [`reject`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) those that are not of the right type or whether you want to [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) and apply that function only [`when`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#when) this predicate is true.

### Update

Trying to work your full requirements, as much as I understand them, you might try something like:

```
const simplifyAll = over(
  lensProp('included'), 
  map(when(propEq('type', 'mobile_screen_components'), simplify))
)

simplifyAll(data)
```

This leaves a lot of `undefined`s in many of the `relationships/items/data`  lists.  If you want to get rid of them, you might update `simplify` to add `reject(isNil)` after `flatten`:

```
const simplify = over(
  lensProp('relationships'), 
  pipe(pluck('data'), values, flatten, reject(isNil), objOf('data'), objOf('items'))
)
```

You can see this version too in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?var%20data%20%3D%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22title%22%3A%20%22Watch%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20%7B%22mobile_screen_components%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_1%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_2%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_3%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_4%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_5%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221_6%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screens%22%7D%2C%20%22included%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A43%3A16.549Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22House%20Republicans%20renew%20call%20amid%20fresh%20Comey%20concerns%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20238912%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22on_air%7Coutnumbered%22%2C%20%22politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%22%2C%20%22politics%7Chouse_representatives%7Crepublicans%22%2C%20%22personality%7Csandra_smith%22%2C%20%22personality%7Ckatie_pavlich%22%2C%20%22primary_politics%22%2C%20%22personality%7Cmarie_harf%22%2C%20%22politics%7Chouse_representatives%22%2C%20%22personality%7Charris_faulkner%22%2C%20%22personality%7Candrew_p_napolitano%22%2C%20%22personality%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A50%3A13.471Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A47%3A35.519Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A32%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_55907%2C27023001_5590720024001%2C30873001_5590720024001%2C32416001_5590720024001%2C32423001_5590720024001%2C32792001_5590720024001%2C32896001_5590720024001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590729403001_5590720024001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Is%202nd%20special%20counsel%20needed%20to%20probe%202016%20controversies%3F%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590720024001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A05%3A26.575Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Stories%20surface%20of%20neighbors%20helping%20neighbors%20as%20some%20hurricane%20survivors%20in%20Puerto%20Rico%20say%20they%27re%20still%20waiting%20for%20help%3B%20Garret%20Tenney%20reports%20from%20Catano%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20126207%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22on_air%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%7Caftermath%22%2C%20%22primary_us%22%2C%20%22personality%7Cgarrett_tenney%22%2C%20%22us%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%7Cdisaster_response%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%7Churricanes_typhoons%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A20%3A13.501Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A19%3A03.325Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A36%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559068%2C2893001_5590670324001%2C3326001_5590670324001%2C3701001_5590670324001%2C4254001_5590670324001%2C5638001_5590670324001%2C5662001_5590670324001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590694198001_5590670324001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Hurricane%20relief%20in%20Puerto%20Rico%20a%20do-it-yourself%20affair%3F%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590670324001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A05%3A02.459Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Man%20hospitalized%20and%20treated%20for%20burns%20in%20St.%20Petersburg%2C%20Florida%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%2027348%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22personality%7Cjon_scott%22%2C%20%22on_air%22%2C%20%22primary_us%22%2C%20%22us%7Cus_regions%7Csoutheast%22%2C%20%22us%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22us%7Cus_regions%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A15%3A10.113Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A12%3A28.582Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A46%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559068%2C1237001_5590665282001%2C2851001_5590665282001%2C3115001_5590665282001%2C3140001_5590665282001%2C3672001_5590665282001%2C3953001_5590665282001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590693231001_5590665282001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Paraglider%20crashes%20into%20powerlines%20in%20Florida%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590665282001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A57%3A09.364Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Critics%20claim%20the%20attorney%20general%27s%20defense%20of%20free%20speech%20on%20campus%20is%20at%20odds%20with%20his%20belief%20that%20athletes%20should%20stand%20for%20the%20national%20anthem%3B%20Rachel%20Brand%2C%20associate%20attorney%20general%20for%20the%20Justice%20Department%2C%20weighs%20in%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20285460%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22politics%7Cexecutive_branch%22%2C%20%22politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%22%2C%20%22primary_politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%7Chappening_now%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22personality%7Cheather_childers%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A10%3A09.819Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T16%3A09%3A29.491Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A26%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559067%2C1425001_5590660900001%2C1430001_5590660900001%2C1610001_5590660900001%2C1894001_5590660900001%2C1905001_5590660900001%2C3646001_5590660900001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590688820001_5590660900001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Is%20Jeff%20Sessions%27%20stance%20on%20NFL%20protests%20hypocritical%3F%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590660900001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A32%3A00.463Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22XXX411%3A%20Speculation%20over%20the%20success%20of%20Chelsea%20Handler%27s%20Netflix%20show%20%27Chelsea%27%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%2060992%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22personality%7Ccarley_shimkus%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%22%2C%20%22primary_entertainment%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%7CXXX_411%22%2C%20%22entertainment%7Cnews_gossip%22%2C%20%22special%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22special%7Capple_news%22%2C%20%22entertainment%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A45%3A42.423Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A44%3A01.873Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559063%2C0350001_5590611978001%2C4054001_5590611978001%2C4066001_5590611978001%2C4068001_5590611978001%2C4179001_5590611978001%2C4719001_5590611978001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590630770001_5590611978001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Is%20Chelsea%20Handler%27s%20Netflix%20show%20a%20flop%3F%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590611978001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A40%3A31.796Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Senate%20majority%20whip%20denies%20the%20proposal%20is%20a%20tax%20cut%20for%20the%20rich%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20335147%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22personality%7Cjon_scott%22%2C%20%22politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%22%2C%20%22politics%7Csenate%22%2C%20%22politics%7Cfinance%22%2C%20%22primary_politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%7Chappening_now%22%2C%20%22politics%7Csenate%7Crepublicans%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22politics%7Cfinance%7Ctaxes%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A45%3A33.457Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A43%3A49.159Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A16%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559064%2C4614001_5590646037001%2C4769001_5590646037001%2C4793001_5590646037001%2C6299001_5590646037001%2C6772001_5590646037001%2C8774001_5590646037001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590647480001_5590646037001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Cornyn%3A%20GOP%20tax%20plan%20will%20lower%20Americans%27%20cost%20of%20living%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590646037001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A39%3A51.772Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22XXX411%3A%20Steven%20Tyler%20returned%20to%20the%20US%20saying%20he%20is%20%27not%20in%20a%20life%20threatening%20condition%27%20but%20needs%20to%20deal%20with%20a%20medical%20issue%20%27immediately%27%20to%20maintain%20future%20scheduled%20performances%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%2037162%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22personality%7Ccarley_shimkus%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%22%2C%20%22primary_entertainment%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%7CXXX_411%22%2C%20%22entertainment%7Cnews_gossip%22%2C%20%22special%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22special%7Capple_news%22%2C%20%22entertainment%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A45%3A22.346Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A43%3A28.501Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559064%2C2556001_5590645736001%2C3185001_5590645736001%2C5970001_5590645736001%2C6137001_5590645736001%2C6138001_5590645736001%2C6257001_5590645736001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590642184001_5590645736001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Steven%20Tyler%20returns%20to%20US%20for%20medical%20care%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590645736001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A36%3A12.404Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22XXX411%3A%20%27Below%20Deck%27%20Captain%20Lee%20Rosbach%20reveals%20some%20of%20his%20most%20outrageous%20encounters%20with%20the%20rich%20and%20famous%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%2050580%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22personality%7Ccarley_shimkus%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%22%2C%20%22primary_entertainment%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%22%2C%20%22web_exclusives%7Cdigital_originals%7CXXX_411%22%2C%20%22entertainment%7Cnews_gossip%22%2C%20%22special%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22special%7Capple_news%22%2C%20%22entertainment%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A45%3A13.353Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A42%3A13.513Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_55906%2C38161001_5590632520001%2C38162001_5590632520001%2C38163001_5590632520001%2C40593001_5590632520001%2C40893001_5590632520001%2C40982001_5590632520001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590640190001_5590632520001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22%27Below%20Deck%27%20Captain%3A%20Craziest%20requests%20from%20rich%20guests%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590632520001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A21%3A18.499Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Residents%20evacuated%20as%20blaze%20swells%20to%20over%202%2C000%20acres%3B%20Anita%20Vogel%20reports%20from%20Los%20Angeles%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%2095935%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22on_air%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%7Cfires%22%2C%20%22us%7Cus_regions%7Csouthwest%22%2C%20%22primary_us%22%2C%20%22us%22%2C%20%22us%7Cdisasters%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22us%7Cus_regions%22%2C%20%22personality%7Canita_vogel%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A40%3A08.954Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A35%3A42.636Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T14%3A38%3A00.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559061%2C1788001_5590607184001%2C2600001_5590607184001%2C3100001_5590607184001%2C3101001_5590607184001%2C5353001_5590607184001%2C6165001_5590607184001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20537%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590636201001_5590607184001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%20952%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Southern%20California%20wildfires%20at%2015%20percent%20containment%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590607184001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A05%3A47.024Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22Senate%20Foreign%20Relations%20Committee%20chairman%20speaks%20out%20on%20%27America%27s%20Newsroom%27%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20309525%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22on_air%7Camericas_newsroom%22%2C%20%22politics%22%2C%20%22on_air%22%2C%20%22politics%7Csenate%22%2C%20%22primary_politics%22%2C%20%22politics%7Csenate%7Crepublicans%22%2C%20%22personality%7Cshannon_bream%22%2C%20%22special%22%2C%20%22personality%22%2C%20%22special%7Capple_news%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A10%3A08.627Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T15%3A09%3A00.001Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22start_air_date%22%3A%20%222017-09-27T14%3A45%3A25.000Z%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22MP4%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_559059%2C0940001_5590587262001%2C0942001_5590587262001%2C0956001_5590587262001%2C2773001_5590587262001%2C3060001_5590587262001%2C3067001_5590587262001%2C.mp4.csmil%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20506%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F09%2F27%2F694940094001_5590593664001_5590587262001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%20900%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Sen.%20Corker%20explains%20decision%20not%20to%20seek%20re-election%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%225590587262001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22display_type%22%3A%20%22shelf%22%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Featured%20Playlist%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%221_1%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20%7B%22articles%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22playlists%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22shows%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22video%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22videos%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20%5B%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590720024001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590670324001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590665282001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590660900001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590611978001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590646037001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590645736001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590632520001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590607184001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%225590587262001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%5D%5D%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222011-10-26T14%3A27%3A41.808Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%20Channel%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20-1%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22live_stream%7Cfnc%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-05-08T16%3A11%3A22.585Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222012-01-02T19%3A59%3A57.030Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22FLV%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffnctve-i.akamaihd.net%2Fhls%2Flive%2F200669%2Ffnctve%2Fplaylist.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F01%2F16%2F694940094001_5283902812001_1241186546001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%20Channel%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%221241186546001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222011-10-31T17%3A50%3A26.779Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22XXX%20Business%20Network%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20-1%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22live_stream%7Cfbn%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-05-08T16%3A11%3A40.248Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222013-12-12T14%3A51%3A26.873Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22FLV%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffbntve-i.akamaihd.net%2Fhls%2Flive%2F200667%2Ffbntve%2Fplaylist.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2015%2F11%2F13%2F694940094001_4611160798001_1280x720-XXXbusiness-b.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22XXX%20Business%20Network%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%221251429410001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22display_type%22%3A%20%22shelf%22%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Live%20TV%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%221_2%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20%7B%22articles%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22playlists%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22shows%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22video%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%2C%20%22videos%22%3A%20%7B%22data%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221241186546001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22id%22%3A%20%221251429410001%22%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%7D%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22mobile_screen_components%22%7D%2C%20%7B%22attributes%22%3A%20%7B%22created_date%22%3A%20%222012-12-05T20%3A43%3A49.351Z%22%2C%20%22description%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%20Radio%22%2C%20%22duration%22%3A%20-1%2C%20%22fn__media_tags%22%3A%20%5B%22live_stream%22%5D%2C%20%22fn__tve_authentication_required%22%3A%20false%2C%20%22ima__content_source_id%22%3A%20%222056%22%2C%20%22last_modified_date%22%3A%20%222017-05-22T15%3A24%3A17.218Z%22%2C%20%22last_published_date%22%3A%20%222017-03-30T22%3A07%3A30.619Z%22%2C%20%22live_stream%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22publisher%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%22%2C%20%22streams%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22mime_type%22%3A%20%22FLV%22%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ffnurtmp-f.akamaihd.net%2Fi%2FFNRADIOHDS_1%4092141%2Fmaster.m3u8%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22thumbnail%22%3A%20%7B%22height%22%3A%20720%2C%20%22url%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmedia2.XXXXX.com%2FBrightCove%2F694940094001%2F2017%2F03%2F30%2F694940094001_5379614307001_2013931500001-vs.jpg%3FpubId%3D694940094001%22%2C%20%22width%22%3A%201280%7D%2C%20%22title%22%3A%20%22News%20Corp%20Radio%22%7D%2C%20%22id%22%3A%20%222013931500001%22%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22relationships%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22type%22%3A%20%22videos%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22jsonapi%22%3A%20%7B%22version%22%3A%20%221.0%22%7D%2C%20%22links%22%3A%20undefined%2C%20%22meta%22%3A%20undefined%7D%0A%0Aconst%20simplify%20%3D%20over%28%0A%20%20lensProp%28%27relationships%27%29%2C%20%0A%20%20pipe%28pluck%28%27data%27%29%2C%20values%2C%20flatten%2C%20reject%28isNil%29%2C%20objOf%28%27data%27%29%2C%20objOf%28%27items%27%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20simplifyAll%20%3D%20over%28%0A%20%20lensProp%28%27included%27%29%2C%20%0A%20%20map%28when%28propEq%28%27type%27%2C%20%27mobile_screen_components%27%29%2C%20simplify%29%29%0A%29%0A%0AsimplifyAll%28data%29)**.

Finally, if this is the only use of the `simplify` function, you could move it inline.  I would recommend against it, as the resulting wall of text is unlikely to be as readable as the above version.  But it's your call.

Comment: not entirely sure how to put it all together tbh! playing around now...

Comment: figured it out! ```const simplify = over(
  lensProp('relationships'), 
  pipe(pluck('data'), values, flatten, objOf('data'), objOf('items'))
)

R.map(
  item => {
    const hasMSC = propEq('type', 'mobile_screen_components');
    if(hasMSC(item)) {
      return simplify(item);
    }
    return item;
  }
  ,data.included)```